# Diagonalization of matrix of binomial probabilities

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I am interested in studying the properties of an $(N+1) \times (N+1)$ matrix with entries

$$ A_{xy} = \binom{N}{x} \Big(\frac{y}{N}\Big)^x \Big(1-\frac{y}{N}\Big)^{N-x}, $$

where $x,y=0,\dots,N$. In particular, is there a straightforward way to diagonalize it?

A related problem that I am interested in is diagonalizing

$$ B_{xy} = \binom{N}{x} \rho(y)^x \big(1-\rho(y)\big)^{N-x}, $$

where

$$ \rho(y) = \frac{y}{N}(1-\mu) + (1-\frac{y}{N})\mu, $$

i.e. $\rho$ interpolates between $\mu$ and $1-\mu$ as $y$ goes from $0$ to $N$.

***EDIT:***
Here are some additional details. The matrix $B$ arises in the context of population genetics.

In particular, consider a population of $N$ individuals that have one of 2 alleles at a locus. The population at the next generation is formed by randomly selecting $N$ new individuals, with replacement, from the current population, and each new individual has an independent probability $\mu$ of mutating to the other allele. Then, the probability that there are $x$ individuals with the first allele in the new generation, given $y$ individuals with the first allele in the old generation, is precisely $B_{xy}$.

Also, the matrix $A$, which might be easier to analyze, arises in the limit of $\mu\ll 1$. Both $A$ and $B$ are left stochastic matrices, and hence have a unique largest eigenvalue $1$. There is also a symmetry

$$A_{xy}=A_{N-x,N-y},$$

and similarly for $B$.

In population genetics, it is well-known that the stationary distribution of this mutation-selection process transitions from being peaked in the middle when $\mu N$ is large, to peaked at the ends when $\mu N$ is small (this is corroborated by numerically diagonalizing $B$). But I am not aware of literature analyzing this in the *discrete*-time setting, as I have described. Any insight or pointers to literature are greatly appreciated!